# ForEach Error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a foreach loop for the amount of some textfields.
Every thing works but the only thing that is not working is when I send a form.
I get the error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

But when I restart the app the information that I put in wil go to the Firestore database.

I think that I mis something in the foreach loop.

The code from the foreach loop is:

```
@Published var boxNumberIdentificatie: [String] = [""]

let aantal = routesData.boxNumberIdentificatie.count

ForEach(0...aantal, id: \.self){i in
       Section(header: Text("BoxIdentificatie (\(i))")) {
         TextField("", text: $routesData.boxNumberIdentificatie[i])
         .font(isMacOS() ? .title3 : .body)

         }
    }
```

The error is in this line:

```
TextField("", text: $routesData.boxNumberIdentificatie[i])
```

I hope that somebody can help me..
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. What's `aantal`? Are you ever mutating it?

Comment: No one knows what `aantal` is.

Comment: I'm sorry @DávidPásztor I have add it to my question.

Comment: Als @JoakimDanielson I'm sorry, I have added to my question

Comment: That's still not a [mcve]. Please read the link to understand what a [mcve] means. If anyone copies the code from your question, they must be able to build and run it without needing to make changes to it. That's not the case with your code.

Comment: I understand, but when I want to do that stack overflow has a maximum of code.. And my question wil not go online. I think that the problem is inside my code here.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022

Answer (score 1):

```
ForEach(0...aantal, id: \.self){i in
```

This is counting one-past the end of the list. You meant:

```
ForEach(0..<aantal, id: \.self){i in
```